# How to insert record from one table to another?

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables with same column e.g ID,SupplierID,ConditionValue,Status,Deleted and I insert data as in Code

```
INSERT INTO SCM_SupplierShippingRateHistory  
SELECT *           
FROM SCM_SupplierShippingRate          
WHERE  Id NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM dbo.GetIDsTableFromIDsList(@NonDeleteShippingIDs))        
AND SupplierId= @SupplierID        
AND ConditionValue IS NULL    
AND Deleted=0
```

I want to insert same data but I want to set status =4 how can I do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly choose the columns.

```
INSERT INTO SCM_SupplierShippingRateHistory 
(
    Col1,
    Col2,
    .
    .
    .
    Status
) 
SELECT  Col1,
        Col2,
        .
        .
        .
        4 AS [Status]

FROM    SCM_SupplierShippingRate          
WHERE   Id NOT IN
        (
            SELECT ID 
            FROM   dbo.GetIDsTableFromIDsList(@NonDeleteShippingIDs)
        )        
        AND SupplierId= @SupplierID        
        AND ConditionValue IS NULL    
        AND Deleted=0
```

Comment: kindly tell me in Code please

Answer (score 0):

you can set status like this.

```
INSERT INTO SCM_SupplierShippingRateHistory  
SELECT ID,SupplierID,ConditionValue,4 AS Status,Deleted           
FROM SCM_SupplierShippingRate          
WHERE  Id NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM dbo.GetIDsTableFromIDsList(@NonDeleteShippingIDs))        
AND SupplierId= @SupplierID        
AND ConditionValue IS NULL    
AND Deleted=0
```